# Пробелы с градусами Цельсия ставятся или нет?

Tags: пробелы

Так отбивается градус Цельсия от цифры? 20°C например....Логичнее слитно писать... Грамота говорит о пробелах, но это ведь чушь....
[https://orfogrammka.ru/типографика/знаки_номер_процент_параграф_градус_с_пробелом/](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC/)
Здесь как-то неопределенно...

Comment: Почему логичнее? На чём вы основываетесь?

Comment: а зачем отбивать? Знак процента не отбиваете от цифры?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: «20 °C» с пробелом.

---

Согласно действующему [ГОСТ 8.417-2002 ЕДИНИЦЫ ВЕЛИЧИН](https://docs.cntd.ru/document/1200031406):

> **8 Правила написания обозначений единиц**
> ...
>
> Между последней цифрой числа и обозначением единицы оставляют пробел.
>
> Правильно:
>  100 kW; 100 кВт
>  80 %
>  20 °С
>  (1/60) s⁻¹.
>
> Неправильно:
>  100kW; 100кВт
>  80%
>  20°С
>  1/60/s⁻¹.

---

> По правилам типографского набора знак градуса ставится сразу после
> числового обозначения величины размерности угла или температуры без
> всякого пробела, однако **если в случае с температурой указывается также
> шкала, по которой производится измерение (по Цельсию, по Фаренгейту и
> т. п.), знак градуса отбивается от числовой величины неразрывным
> пробелом** (более точно, используется третная шпация), а символ шкалы
> следует непосредственно за знаком градуса без пробелов.
>
> [[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0)]

---

> In the case of degrees of temperature, three scientific and
> engineering standards bodies (the International Bureau of Weights and
> Measures, the International Organization for Standardization and the
> U.S. Government Printing Office) **prescribe printing temperatures
> with a space between the number and the degree symbol, e.g. 10 °C.**
> However, in many works with professional typesetting, including
> scientific works published by the University of Chicago Press or
> Oxford University Press, the degree symbol is printed with no spaces
> between the number, the symbol, and the Latin letters "C" or "F"
> representing Celsius or Fahrenheit, respectively, e.g. 10°C.[4][5]
> This is also the practice of the University Corporation for
> Atmospheric Research, which operates the National Center for
> Atmospheric Research.
>
> Что касается градусов
> температурны, то три научных и технических органа по стандартизации
> (Международное бюро мер и весов, Международная организация по
> стандартизации и Типография правительства США) **предписывают печать
> температуры с пробелом между числом и символом градуса, например 10
> °С.** Однако во многих работах с профессиональным набором, включая
> научные работы, опубликованные в University of Chicago Press или
> Oxford University Press, символ градуса печатается без пробелов между
> цифрой, символом и латинскими буквами «C» или «F», обозначающими
> градусы Цельсия или Фаренгейта соответственно, например 10°C. Это
> также практика сущетвует в Университетской корпорации атмосферных
> исследований, которая управляет Национальным центром атмосферных
> исследований.
>
> [[wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_symbol)]

Comment: В приведенной ссылке: Правильно:  20°, Неправильно: 20 °.....    Это противоречит....

Comment: @flossyU Это если без «С».

Comment: Исправьте: _согласно (чему?) действующ**ему**_…

Comment: @slava1947 Спасибо, исправил. Я сам в этом вопросе раньше разбирался и выяснил, что сейчас правильно только в дательном падеже. Однако, видимо, потому что часто употребляется неправильно, засел в памяти родильный падеж.